# How to render page template from db?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have mezzanine project, and I want to put templates into database as blocks and then I want to build custom page by adding those blocks (in different sets).

In pure Django it's simple, something like this:

```
s = TemplatesModel.objects.get(name='news_block').content
t = Template(s)
t.render(Context(dict(var_a='something', var_b=1)))
```

But I would like to use the mezzanine functionality - with this feature. How to do it?